# load(url(....)) vs download.file in R. Why the latter doesn't work when downloading .Rdata files?

Tags: r, function, url, download

I'm reading some of my old R notes and I'm faced with something that make things confusing to me. [Here](http://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/statistics%2Fproject%2Fgss.Rdata) you can find a dummy database with .Rdata extension.

When I use `load` + `url` the database is downloaded and read properly:

```
load(url("http://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/statistics%2Fproject%2Fgss.Rdata"))
str(gss)
```

But when I try to accomplish same thing using `download.file` and then `readRDS` I got an error:

```
URLtest <- "http://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/statistics%2Fproject%2Fgss.Rdata"
download.file(URLtest,"myfile", method="curl")
readRDS("myfile)
Error in readRDS ("myfile"): unknown input format
```

The reason I called `readRDS` can be found [here](https://yihui.org/en/2017/12/save-vs-saverds/).

So if `load` is not advised because its side effects (such as silently overwriting files) why does it work in cases like this?

Any reference and comment will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the file was created with `save()`, then you need to use `load()` to open it. If it was created with `saveRDS()`, then you can use `readRDS()` to load it. You cannot open the same file with both `load()` and `readRDS()` -- those are two different file formats. It is customary to use an `.Rdata` extension for files created with `save()` and `.rds` for files created with `saveRDS()`.

Comment: The problem is precisely that I didn't use neither save() nor saveRDS() as you can see in the code I shared. That's why I don't understand what's happening "behind the cameras".

Comment: Whoever created the `Rdata` file that you are downloading used one of those two function. There's nothing you can to do change how the file was created; you just have to use the correct function to open it.

Comment: So basically I'm doing nothing grow. It's the file itself which requires to be loaded with a specific function. Thank you very much!